# Eroor while using below CASE STATEMENT related to DATE

Tags: sql, oracle

Below QUOTE_REGISTER_DATE datatype is varchar2, when running below script it's giving error.

```
select CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(QUOTE_REGISTER_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'DY')) = 'SAT' THEN 0
            ELSE SAT_SUN_COUNT
       END SAT_SUN_COUNT
from tablename;
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: ORA-12702: invalid NLS parameter string used in SQL function

Comment: Move the bracket from after `, 'DY'` to before. (And also consider adding a third parameter of `'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'` to the `TO_CHAR` otherwise your code will break if anyone changes their session date language).

Comment: BTW, that's a `case` _expression_, not statement.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an error in the function, write it like this:

```
select CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(QUOTE_REGISTER_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'DY') = 'SAT' THEN 0 ELSE SAT_SUN_COUNT END SAT_SUN_COUNT 
from tablename
```

And for another time, add the error you get to the question, we cannot just guess what is wrong. For this question, it was obvious.
[Edit]: removed the second of the '))'. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: You have to one ")" that should be removed here `'DY'))`.

Comment: Thanx for the support mates, below query is working now - CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(QUOTE_REGISTER_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'DY') = 'SAT' THEN 0 ELSE SAT_SUN_COUNT END SAT_SUN_COUNT